# Badge not appearing on tab bar item when set in notification callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to set the badge in my tab bar to "1" on the 4th tab when a notification is received by my app. Strangely enough, my console says that the method is firing (see NSLog "Fire!"), however the badge doesn't appear on my tab bar item once the notification is received? Am I missing something?

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

        NSLog(@"App notification received!");
        // do stuff when app is active

    }else{
        // do stuff when app is in background

        static int i=1;
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = i++;

        NSLog(@"App notification received background!");
    }
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void) myNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *) notification {


    [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setBadgeValue:@"1"];


    NSLog(@"Fire!");
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myNotificationReceived:) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];

}
```

Comment: Few suggestions: What happens when you call `[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setBadgeValue:@"1"]` from `viewDidLoad`? Is this line called from main thread? Do you have a More... tab perhaps?

Comment: _"contains >= 5 items"_ `objectAtIdex:` throws an exception for out-of-bounds indexes.

Comment: try this  [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:@"1"]; does the 1 appear on hardcoded index?

Comment: Note that you're trying to set the 5th tab, not the 4th.

Comment: @BashirSidani Tried this, still no "1" appearing. Though, my NSLog "Fire!" still shows in the console, leading me to believe that the method is executed.

Comment: @meaning-matters tried the code with objectAtIndex 3 as well, still no badge appearing.

Comment: @meaning-matters Oddly enough, when I put that same line in the controller's viewDidLoad, no badge appears either?

Comment: Stop the debugger in`viewDidLoad` and print (using the `po` command) `self.tabBarController.tabBar.items`. What do you get?

Comment: you are doing this in the App delegate. meaning that you are trying to add the badge before the UItabbarcontroller is even loaded. You need to do this after the UITabbarcontroller is initiated in the viewdidload

Comment: @BashirSidani But AppDelegate only attempts to fire the nsnotification method when a notification has been received? Which is after the tab bar loads and the app is opened? Also, see above comment - if I set the badge number in viewDidLoad it doesn't appear either?

Comment: makes sense, try putting your line of code directly after your initiation of the UItabbarcontroller (and after its items are added) can you see it updating?

Comment: @Brittany Did you try with `UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;` Then you can set the badge like `[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";` ?

Comment: call `postNotificationName ` by using timer.... Call it after 1 sec. ..... So that the UITab gets time to get initialize... Just in case...

Comment: @PiyushPatel Added self.window.rootViewController line to my notification method and still no dice.

Comment: @PiyushPatel Added self.window.rootViewController line to my AppDelegate and NOW it works - thank you!! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No NSNotification method needed - the following fixed the issue in **AppDelegate.m**:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

        UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";


        NSLog(@"App notification received!");
        // do stuff when app is active

    }else{


        static int i=1;
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = i++;

        //  NSLog(@"App notification received!");

        NSLog(@"App notification received background!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:nil];  set your count or number at place of nil to show on tab bar

try this it may help you